# CoreData Swift: Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    // need to add a device?
    if profile == nil {
        if let name = nameTextField.text, species = speciesTextField.text, dob: NSDate = datePicker.date, entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Profile", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) where !name.isEmpty && !species.isEmpty {
            profile = Profile(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
            profile?.name = name
            profile?.species = species
            profile?.dob = dob
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I run my app, this part of code produces 'Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'. I am certain that name,species and dob do contain data as it shows in the console. Do you have any idea what variable could contain nil? I am using core data and am unfamiliar with it.

**Screen:**
[image]

**Entities:**
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the debug area and checked which variable is nil? Just curious, can you show a screenshot of your entities?

Comment: I think I've found it, its your `managedObjectContext`. You're implicitly unwrapping it and causes it to crash.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I cant see any variable that is nil on the debug screen (see updated post for image).

Comment: Well, your `profile` is `nil` (which is ok) but your `managedObjectContext` is nil as well which causes it to crash when you uses it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your screenshot, it says:

```
managedObjectContext = (NSManagedObjectContext!)nil
```

So most likely this is the cause of your crash.

Comment: This must be it, thanks. I assumed the managedObjectContext would initialise itself when i created the entity. Back to the documentation I think.

Answer (score 0):

It very well could be one of your text fields producing the nil value. Put in a break point and check them (and the datePicker) for nil. Are you using IBOutlets, or were these created programmatically?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I used IBOutlets. As you can see from the screenshot (updated above) the debugger shows the text fields as having a value.